# Representation theory - proving dimension of subspace of fixed vectors equal to number of orbits

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, representation-theory, group-actions

> Denote by $a$ a group action of $G$ on a finite set $X$, and consider the representation $(\rho_a,\mathbb{F}X)$ defined by $(\rho_a)_g(\sum_{x\in X}a_xx)=\sum_{x\in X}a_x(g.x)$. Prove that the dimension of $\mathbb{F}X^G=\{v\in\mathbb{F}X:\forall g\in G,(\rho_a)_g(v)=v\}$ is equal to the number of orbits of $a$.

To be clear, $\mathbb{F}X$ is our notation to the $\operatorname{Span}_{\mathbb{F}}\{x\in X\}$ - formal sums of elements in $X$. First I tried to understand when an element is in $\mathbb{F}X^G$ - $\sum_{x\in X}a_xx\in \mathbb{F}X^G\iff \forall g\in G, (\rho_a)_g(\sum_{x\in X}a_xx)=\sum_{x\in X}a_x(g.x)=\sum_{x\in X}a_xx$ and I think that $\mathbb{F}X^G=\operatorname{Span}\{x\in X:g.x=x\}$, so I tried maybe using Burnside lemma - but I think this is wrong since $\{x\in X:g.x=x\}$ maybe empty (for example a free action) but every action has atleast $1$ orbit.

Any hint would be helpful

Comment: It is true that $\Bbb F(X^G)={\rm span}\{ x\in X\mid gx=x\}$, but we're talking about $(\Bbb FX)^G$, which in general is a bigger subspace of $\Bbb F(X)$ than $\Bbb F(X^G)$ is.

Comment: @runway44 that's true, I'll delete my comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for each $g\in G$ we have:

$\rho(g)(\sum\limits_{x\in X}a_xx)=\sum\limits_{x\in X} a_x(g.x)=\sum\limits_{x\in X}a_{g^{-1}x}x$

Since the sums are formal, this element is equal to $\sum\limits_{x\in X} a_xx$ if and only if we have $a_x=a_{g^{-1}x}$ for all $x\in X$.

So the sum will belong to $\mathbb{F}X^G$ if and only if the following holds: if two elements of $X$ belong to the same orbit then their coefficients must be equal. And now there is a very natural way to construct a basis of $\mathbb{F}X^G$, which will prove your claim.

Comment: What do you mean by their coefficients? Elements in $X$ don't have coefficients. I don't think I understand the last three statements

Comment: I mean, in the sum $\sum\limits_{x\in X} a_xx$, I call $a_x$ the coefficient of $x$. The sum belongs to $\mathbb{F}X^G$ iff $a_{gx}=a_x$ for all $g\in G, x\in X$. In other words, elements in the same orbit must have equal coefficients.

Comment: I think I understand, so basically $\mathbb{F}X^{G}=\text{Span}\{\sum_{x\in\mathcal{O}_i}x:1\leq i\leq n\}$ where $\mathcal{O}_1,\dots,\mathcal{O}_n$ are the orbits?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. This set is clearly a basis of $\mathbb{F}X^G$, and so the dimension is the number of orbits.